# Are system calls ran on the same thread?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

When using the multi-threaded approach to solve IO Bound problems in Python, this works by freeing the GIL. Let us suppose we have Thread1 which takes 10 seconds to read a file, during this 10 seconds it does not require the GIL and can leave Thread2 to execute code. Thread1 and Thread2 are effectively running in parallel because Thread1 is doing system call operations and can execute independently of Thread2, however Thread1 is still executing code.

Now, suppose we have a setup using `asyncio` or any asynchronous programming code. When we do something such as,

```
file_content = await ten_second_long_file_read()
```

During the time in which `await` is called, system calls are done to read the content of the files and when it is done an event is sent back and code execution can be later continue. During the time we are `await`'ing, other code can be ran.

My confusion comes from the fact that asynchronous programming is primarily single threaded. With the multiple threaded approach when T1 is reading from a file, it is still performing code execution, it simply free'd the GIL to perform work in parallel with another thread. However with asynchronous programming, when we are `await`ing, how is it performing other tasks when we are waiting, aswell as reading data in a **single** thread? I understand the multiple-threaded idea, but not asynchronous because it is still performing the system calls in a single thread. With asynchronous programming it has nowhere to free the GIL to, considering there is only one thread. Is `asyncio` secretly using threads?

Comment: Threads free the GIL ... no they don't.

Comment: @jwal Maybe not the thread itself, but I mean something allows the Thread to let another Thread hold the GIL

Comment: Threads use a single CPU. Only one thread runs at a time. The GIL is a limitation however the fact there is only ONE cpu used is the first limitation. ```asyncio``` does not secretly use threads, that would defeat the benefits.

Comment: If an asyncio Task makes a blocking system call, such as when using a network socket, that will block the event loop.  To avoid this, the asyncio library creates threads under the hood when required.  So to you, the application programmer, asyncio looks single-threaded.  If you want to read a large file asynchronously, that is not supported by the asyncio package.  A third party package, aiofile, is available.  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62501080/async-file-read-with-aiofile

Answer (score 0):

The number of filehandles is independent of the GIL, and threads. Posix `select` documentation gives a bit of an idea of the distinct mechanism around file handles.

To illustrate I created three files, `1.txt` etc. These are just:

```
1
one
```

Obviously open for reading is ok but not for writing. To make a ten second read I just held the filehandle open for ten seconds, reading the first line, waiting 10 seconds, then reading the second line.

#### asyncio version

```
import asyncio
from threading import active_count

do = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']

async def ten_second_long_file_read():
    while do:
        doing = do.pop()
        with open(doing, 'r') as f:
            print(f.readline().strip())
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            print(f"threads {active_count()}")
            print(f.readline().strip())

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(asyncio.create_task(ten_second_long_file_read()),
                         asyncio.create_task(ten_second_long_file_read()))

asyncio.run(main())
```

This produces a very predictable output and as expected, one thread only.

```
3
2
threads 1
three
1
threads 1
two
threads 1
one
```

#### threading - changes

Remove async of course. Swap `asyncio.sleep(10)` for `time.sleep(10)`. The main change is the calling function.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as e:
    e.submit(ten_second_long_file_read)
    e.submit(ten_second_long_file_read)
```

Also a fairly predictable output, however you cannot rely on this.

```
3
2
threads 3
three
threads 3
two
1
threads 2
one
```

Running the same threaded version in debug the output is a bit random, on one run on my computer this was:

```
23

threads 3threads 3

twothree

1
threads 2
one
```

This highlights a difference in threads in that the running thread is pre-emptively switched creating a whole bundle of complexity under the heading *thread safety*. This issue does not exist in `asyncio` as there is a single thread.

#### multi-processing

Similar to the threaded code however `__name__ == '__main__'` is required and the process pool executor provides a snapshot of the context.

```
def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as e:
        e.submit(ten_second_long_file_read)
        e.submit(ten_second_long_file_read)

if __name__ == '__main__':  # required for executor
    main()
```

Two big differences. No shared understanding of the do list so everything is done twice. Processes don't know what the other process has done. More CPU power available, however more work required to manage the load.

Three processes required for this so the overhead is large, however each process only has one thread.

```
3
3
threads 1
threads 1
three
three
2
2
threads 1
threads 1
two
two
1
1
threads 1
threads 1
one
one
```